# Deleting the local storage of a specific domain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm making an extension and while I can delete all the cookies of a specified domain, I can't delete its local storage.

So for example, if I visited The Telegraph's website, it keeps a local storage in my machine:

> Origin: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/
>
> Size on disk: 6.0 KB

I have tried using the remove() method from the storage api:

```
StorageArea.remove("http://www.telegraph.co.uk/");
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in event handler for browserAction.onClicked: StorageArea is not defined
Stack trace: ReferenceError: StorageArea is not defined
```

How can I programmatically make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is a completely different API compared to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage). The former is only available to extensions, while the latter is specific to the domain of the website.

If you want to modify or clear the data in `localStorage` for a specific domain, then just insert a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in the page that invokes `localStorage.clear()`.

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'localStorage.clear()'});
});
```

If you want to clear the localStorage of a different origin, you have to load a page from that origin in a tab or frame and insert a content script in it. For example:

```js
// background.js
var f = document.createElement('iframe');
f.sandbox = ''; // Sandboxed = disable scripts, etc.
f.src = 'http://example.com/#someuniqueid';
f.onloadend = function() {
    f.remove();
};

// content script, declared in manifest file (read the documentation)
if (location.hash === '#someuniqueid') {
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wish there was a way to just do it silently without having to load any pages-- like chrome.cookies.remove()

Comment: @Haque1 You could try using an iframe in the background page.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
   StorageArea.clear(function callback)
```

.remove  accepts key string or array of keys to remove specific items. 
Also i'm not sure if it will access storage of specific domains.
Try to check url before clearing

Comment: If `StorageArea` is not defined as OP's error message indicates certainly wont be able to call `StorageArea.clear`

Comment: Does that delete all local storages? Is there a way to only delete a specific one?

Comment: documentation says if you clear storage on specific domain (meaning the url in browser example.com) it will clear storage of this domain

Comment: I tried it and I'm getting this error: Error in event handler for browserAction.onClicked: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined

Comment: @GenaMoroz yes, my permissions includes "storage". I can get rid of the errors by using: chrome.storage.local.remove("http://www.telegraph.co.uk/");
but it doesn't delete Telegraph's storage

Comment: remove Uses KEY VALUE

Comment: e.g.  localStorage.example  = "1"

chrome.local.remove("example")

will delete that field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58142/discussion-between-haque1-and-gena-moroz).